Error: Exception calling "NextValue" with "0" argument(s): "Category does not exist."
I have this piece of code in would like to run with Powershell on my local machine, try to collect some performance counter value on another machine.
# Define parameters
param (
    [string]$ComputerName = "<machine-address>",
    [string]$CounterPath = "\Processor Information\% Processor Utility\_Total",
    [int]$SamplingIntervalSeconds = 1,
    [int]$TotalDurationSeconds = 3
)

# Validate parameters
if ($SamplingIntervalSeconds -le 0 -or $TotalDurationSeconds -le 0) {
    Write-Error "Sampling interval and total duration must be positive integers."
    exit 1
}

# Create a PerformanceCounter object
$counter = New-Object System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter
$counter.CategoryName = $CounterPath.Split('\')[1]
$counter.CounterName = $CounterPath.Split('\')[2]
$counter.InstanceName = $CounterPath.Split('\')[3]
$counter.MachineName = $ComputerName

# Initialize variables
$totalSamples = 0
$totalValue = 0
$value = 0

# Calculate the number of samples based on the total duration and sampling interval
$numberOfSamples = [math]::Ceiling($TotalDurationSeconds / $SamplingIntervalSeconds)

# Collect samples
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $numberOfSamples; $i++) {
    $value = $counter.NextValue()
    Start-Sleep -Seconds $SamplingIntervalSeconds
    $value = $counter.NextValue()

    # Add value to total sum
    $totalValue += $value
    $totalSamples++

    Write-Output "Sample $($i + 1): $value"
}

# Calculate the average value
if ($totalSamples -gt 0) {
    $averageValue = $totalValue / $totalSamples
    Write-Output "Average Value: $averageValue"
} else {
    Write-Output "No samples collected."
}

when I try to run it with a  the error is:
Exception calling "NextValue" with "0" argument(s): "Category does not exist."
if I put
"[string]$ComputerName = ".",

letting it run locally, it seems working.
I'm running PS as administrator and I'm able to RDP connect to that machine. My user is also part of the local group users in that machine.
NOTE: my "client" machine is win10, the server I'm trying to call () is Win11.
This piece of code worked fine until the server has been updated to Win11.
Someone can help me on that?
Thank you
What I have tried:
Added Administrator and myUser to Performance counter user groups.
Rebuild performance counters (PerformanceCounter Category does not exist even though it exists )
I can see the counter in Performance Monitor, both locally, from my own laptop and from another user virtual machine that has the same grants.
Then, after looking around I found the two commands explained below. In my case, the problem was with the perfOS. (you can always run lodctr /q:Perflib to check what's disabled.)
Then, run: lodctr /e:perfOS (or change perfOS for whatever service is disabled)
TLDR: run lodctr /q:perfOs and lodctr /e:perfOS as Admin
nothing of that helped me.
